# Matching 'Network Location' icons

Tags: powershell, icons

I am using the following code to create a Network Location, but the result is not exactly the same as when doing it manually. The icon from shell32.dll is smaller, lower res and has a frame, as seen here on the left. Is there any way to match the "native" look with PowerShell?

[image]

```
$linkFolder = New-Item -name:$location.name -path:"$nethoodPath\$($location.name)" -type:Directory -errorAction:stop

                        # Create the ini file
                        $desktopIniContent = (
                           '[.ShellClassInfo]',
                           'CLSID2={0AFACED1-E828-11D1-9187-B532F1E9575D}',
                           'Flags=2',
                           'ConfirmFileOp=1'
                        ) -join "`r`n"
                        $desktopIniContent | Out-File -filePath:"$nethoodPath\$($location.name)\Desktop.ini"

                        # Create the shortcut file
                        $link = $shell.Createshortcut("$nethoodPath\$($location.name)\target.lnk")
                        $link.TargetPath = $location.value
                        $link.IconLocation = "%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.DLL, 275"
                        $link.Description = $location.value
                        $link.WorkingDirectory = $location.value
                        $link.Save()

                        # Set attributes on the files & folders
                        Set-ItemProperty "$nethoodPath\$($location.name)\Desktop.ini" -name:Attributes -value:([IO.FileAttributes]::System -bxor [IO.FileAttributes]::Hidden) -errorAction:stop
                        Set-ItemProperty "$nethoodPath\$($location.name)" -name:Attributes -value:([IO.FileAttributes]::ReadOnly) -errorAction:stop
```

Comment: Try with `imageres.dll,137` instead of the `shel32.dll` one

Comment: Mathias, that's the ticket! Thanks!
I think it's time I get my head around some of these resources, since I am doing more and more than just simple PS scripts.

Comment: BTW, post that as an answer rather than comment, so I can check mark it. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icon on the right hand side can be found in **`imageres.dll`** (the Windows **image** **res**ource library), icon 138 (index 137):

```
$link.IconLocation = "%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres,137"
```

---

It would seem that the horrible resolution of the `shell32.dll,275` version is a bug/blunder that has been fixed by Microsoft subsequently:

Windows 7:

[image: Windows 7 Network Location]
*The* `shell32.dll` *version scales horribly*

Windows 10:

[image: Windows 10 Network Location]
*On Windows 10,* `shell32.dll,275` *scales to "Extra Large Icons"-size perfectly fine*